# Magnolia - Blossom XSD not found

Tags: spring, magnolia

I am working with Magnolia 5.3.4 and Blossom 3.0.3 but cannot get past this error in my application config, no idea why i am getting this error and why it cannot be reached.  Anyone experience this issue and know how to get around it?

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.magnolia-cms.com/schema/
     blossom.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element 
     of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
    - cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 
     'blossom:configuration'.
```

application config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:blossom="http://www.magnolia-cms.com/schema/blossom"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
            http://www.magnolia-cms.com/schema/blossom 
            http://www.magnolia-cms.com/schema/blossom.xsd" >

<tx:annotation-driven />   
    <context:annotation-config />
    <blossom:configuration />
    </beans>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XSDs were on the site before but must have been lost in an update / migration recently. A ticket was created within Magnolia's JIRA to add them back. The ticket is internal so I can't point you to it.

However, in the mean time, as a workaround you can disable XML validation in your IDE or configure an alternative location manually. For example in Eclipse in would be under Preferences->XML->XML Catalog select User Specified Entries and then the Add button. You can find a copy of the XSD file in the Blossom module.